# A Question on Step Functions and Measure Theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, step-function

I am self teaching myself on step functions and measure theory. There was a question I am working on in one of my textbooks. The question is this: Assume $ \{ \phi_n \} $ is a sequence of step functions with $\phi_n \geq 0,n \geq1$, and assume that $\psi_n \uparrow B $ everywhere for a simple function B. Let $P_n = \{x | \phi_n(x) > 0 \}$

Prove that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} I(\phi_n) < \infty$ if and only if $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu^*(P_n) < \infty$

Here is what I have so far. Suppose I assume that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} I(\phi_n) < \infty$. Then, I defined a function as follows: $\alpha_n = \phi_n \wedge a_m \chi_{E_m}$.   I am not sure I am on the right track here. Can anyone give me some hints and pointers in order to solve this problem?

Comment: the question doesn't make sense for the standard definition of simple function, that is, if $I(\phi _n)=\int \phi _n$ and $B$ is a simple function then $I(B)<\infty$ by definition of simple function, then the dominated convergence theorem show us that $\lim_{n\to \infty }I(\phi _n)=I(B)$

Comment: This is what the question is written down. Maybe I forgot to mention this: Suppose that $B = c \chi_{C} + d \chi_{D}$, for two disjoint and measurable sets $C,D$ and $c,d \geq 0$. Does this help a little bit?